# Cannot access memory at address while adding breakpoints and running the program

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gdb, breakpoints

I am trying to set the breakpoints as below in gdb.c file.

```
#DISABLING MONITORING OF LINES REFERENCED IN STATIC INITIALIZER
b *0x400ee8
commands
c
end
b *0x400efd
commands
c
end
echo !!!BCT-NEW-EXECUTION\n
run
quit
```

When I run the program, I get this error in the log file.

```
(WorkersMap * const) 0xc350
!!!BCT-VARIABLE *this
/home/zack/workspace_ok_zack/FaultAnalysis/BCT_DATA/check/conf/files/scripts/originalSoftware.gdb.config.txt:1929: Error in sourced command file:
Cannot access memory at address 0xc350
[Inferior 11406 exited]
```

How do I debug this?

Comment: `(WorkersMap * const) 0xc350` in the log is the invalid memory access.  Where does that come from?  If it's an offset in your executable it needs to be adjusted by the base image address, 0x40000, and WorkersMap would be at `(WorkersMap * const) 0x4c350`.

Answer (score 0):

You could be simply trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer. 
One reason could be that you're trying to inspect a coredump on a 32-bit machine while it was running on a 64-bit, then it can't be mapped as expected.

Comment: we are generating the build on 64 bit and running the program on 64 bit only

Comment: Ye, then it's probably that you're trying to dereference a pointer that is not initialized.

Comment: I am trying to use an eclipse plugin which has hardcoded the breakpoint address to monitor the program execution.